# SysML UML Block definition diagram how to hide attributes and operations

Tags: uml, block, papyrus, sysml

I am trying to draw some bdd in my papyrus. I want to hide the attributes and operations. But I couldn't find how to do it. Does anyone know how to combine them as a simple block or hide the attributes and operations?

The only one that [I found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GgGv.jpg) in Papyrus, with the attributes and operations:

[image]

The kind that [I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2bZS.jpg) to have in Paprus, without the details of attributes/operations:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I finally managed to find the solution.  Just [right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7N1P.jpg) the block and then find the option :

[image]